# How to copy ALE hover message to clipboard on vim?

Tags: vim

Is there a way to grab / yank / copy the ALE hover message to a vim register? Having the message on clipboard would be useful for quickly searching the warning or error message elsewhere. It appears that the usual `:redir` or `:let @*` will not work since the hover message is not an output of a vim command per se.